# How can I write a sumo logic query that aggregates a field over time

Tags: artifactory, sumologic

Artifactory cloud comes with some canned queries.

This query aggregates download volume by repo:

```
_sourceCategory=artifactory*
| where _sourceCategory matches "*artifactory/traffic"
| parse regex "(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})\|\d*\|(?<direction>[^|]*)\|\s*(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[^|]*)\|(?<repo>[^:]*):(?<fullfilepath>[^|]*)\|(?<size>\d*)" nodrop
| where direction matches "DOWNLOAD"
| sum(size) by repo
| _sum / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) as sizeinGB
| fields -_sum
| sort by sizeinGB | limit 10
```

This query aggregates data transfer over time:

```
_sourceCategory=artifactory*
| where _sourceCategory matches "*artifactory/traffic"
| parse regex "(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})\|\d*\|(?<direction>[^|]*)\|\s*(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[^|]*)\|(?<repo>[^:]*):(?<fullfilepath>[^|]*)\|(?<size>\d*)" nodrop
| where direction matches "DOWNLOAD"
| timeslice 1h
| sum(size) by _timeslice, direction 
| _sum / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) as sizeinGB | sort by _sum
| fields -_sum
| transpose row _timeslice column direction
```

I'm trying to combine the two to get GB downloaded over time aggregated by repo, but I cannot figure out how to do this. It looks like I have all the info I need in the query but cannot find the right syntax.

I tried to add a timeslice to the query that sums download size by repo but I get

> Field timeslice not found, please check the spelling and try again.

```
_sourceCategory=artifactory*
| where _sourceCategory matches "*artifactory/traffic"
| parse regex "(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})\|\d*\|(?<direction>[^|]*)\|\s*(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|[^|]*)\|(?<repo>[^:]*):(?<fullfilepath>[^|]*)\|(?<size>\d*)" nodrop

| timeslice 1h
| sum(size) by repo
| _sum / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) as sizeinGB
| fields -_sum
| sort by sizeinGB | limit 100
| sort by timeslice
```

Answer (score 0):

remove last line

and make last line this

| sort by sizeinGB, _timeslice | limit 100